# I get different binary data when I convert from byte array

Tags: arrays, byte, bit

my byte array has these first 8 values, 
0 0 12 12 
0 0 127 224

However when I read the bitarray after conversion, 
it has,

0000,0000 0000,0000 0011,0000 0011,0000 
0000,0000 0000,0000 1111,1110 0000,0111

I have no idea why bitarray have these values...

ANybody knows why this is happening?

Code used for the conversion is;

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(args[0]);

BitArray bits = new BitArray(bytes);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the bits need to be read from right to left in order to make sense.

0000,0000
0000,0000
0011,0000  -->  00001100 = 12
0011,0000
0000,0000
0000,0000
1111,1110  -->  01111111 = 127
0000,0111

That's just the way the BitArray works.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xda43a.aspx

```
The first byte in the array represents bits 0 through 7,
the second byte represents bits 8 through 15, and so on.
The Least Significant Bit of each byte represents the lowest index value:
"bytes [0] & 1" represents bit 0,
"bytes [0] & 2" represents bit 1,
"bytes [0] & 4" represents bit 2,
and so on.
```

So the least significant bit of the first byte in the array is bit 0 in the bit array and the second least significant bit of the first byte in the array is bit 1 in the bit array.

I have no idea why they did it that way.

Comment: That still doesn't answer properly why the LSb is on the left end in the string representation.

Comment: Apparently it's related to your CPU architecture - if you were to run this code on a big endian CPU, [the bits would be in the opposite order](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/16ede41d-71a1-4681-b507-9a21746cc138)...

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the bit stream is reversed (as string representation of the bits). If you read it backwards it is OK:

- 224 is `"1110 0000"`, you have it as `"0000 0111"`
- 127 is `"0111 1111"`, you have it as `"0111 1111"`